# ios: change button color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I changed a button color using the following code:

```
[self.testButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but I got a weird button:

[image]

why the button background color didn't change?

Comment: The button background did change, it's just that the button itself is a different view.

Comment: Set testButton style as `UIButtonTypeCustom` and check. It should show red color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and try this,

```
self.testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.testButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.testButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
self.testButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Or else you can use some custom image as the background image for this button.

Answer (score 2):

Change the button type to Custom in Attributes inspector in your .xib then check your code

```
 [self.testButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```